# Actionscript - Adding EventListener to multiple buttons on stage

Tags: actionscript, addeventlistener

I have a little problem with adding EventListener to multiple objects on stage. I have above 40 buttons on stage named "Button01","Button02" .. "Button40", and i'm looking for easiest way to add EventListener to all of them.

Creating something like

```
Button01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doSomething)
Button02.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doSomething)
..
Button40.addEventListener(MouseEvent.Click, doSomething)
```

(Notice the same function).
isn't solution i'm looking for :(.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var cnt:Number;
var cnt_str:String;
for (cnt = 1; cnt <= 40; cnt++) {
    if (cnt < 10) {
        cnt_str = "0" + String(cnt);
    } else {
        cnt_str = String(cnt);
    }
    this["Button" + cnt_str].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doSomething);
}
```

This assumes that this code is in the DocumentClass, or on your timeline somewhere since it is using `this` to access the MovieClips.  If that is not the case then just replace the `this` with a reference of the container.