# dynamically create, add and addEventListener items in flash builder 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, for-loop, addeventlistener, flashbuilder4

I am using Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 and trying to `create`, `add` and `addEventListener` to objects that i created dynamically, in as2 i was doing it by:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    abc[i]doSomeThing;
}
```

How it is in actionScript 3? I searched it much and found nothing, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134618/actionscript-adding-eventlistener-to-multiple-buttons-on-stage

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use AS3.0 in flash

```
for(var i:int=0;i<10;i++){

  abc[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,doSomeThing);

}

 function doSomeThing(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   switch(event.target)
{
    case abc[0]:
    //statements for object 1;
    break;
    case abc[1]:
    //statements for object 2;
    break;
    '
    '
    '
    '
    '
    '
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but the point i didn't get; how can i create and add -for example textinputs- items

Comment: i mean how can i create a text input inside of a for loop and addItem to a panel container like, panel.addItem(abc[i]);